# Set backgroundTint to be compatible with all android versions

Tags: android

I know that `backgroundTint` is only compitable with Android version `5.1.1`.

Is there a way to to set a backgrounTint to be compitable with all Android version?

If i use background it just seem like a photo when a click on it nothing will change , or in another way there is a way to make a `background` just like `backgroundTint` when clicking on it ?

Answer (score -1):

The android documentation here

`http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/TintableBackgroundView.html`

outlines how to receive background tint calls on deceives that are running on APIv20 or lower. Hope that helps you a bit